# LinkedHashMap - неконтролируемое переприсваивание

Tags: java

Делаю подобие бд в виде LinkedHashMap.
При попытке изменить юзеру параметр, он меняется у всех юзеров. Почему когда я получаю параметры юзера в **userparm** и меняю нужные значения, эти параметры меняются у всех пользователей. По сути **logparm** статичен, я его не изменял, а он наследовал параметры у **userparm**.

[image: Код Java]

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В джаве есть примитивы и ссылочные типы данных. То, с чем вы имеете дело, относится именно к ссылочным типам. Посему почитайте про это, инфы более, чем достаточно , все станет на свои места

Comment: А картинкой обязательно было вставлять?